# How to put chunk files in separate folder when run ng build?

Tags: angular, typescript

How to configure  to create separate folder in "dist" folder for all chunk files in angular2?

I have use ngcli and run project with ng build. It creates "dist" folder. That is good.

This is the basic structure of the project:

[image: basic structure of project]

But I want to put all *.chunk.js and *.map files in separate folders in dist. Like

dist/modules/0.chunk.js

dist/modules/0.map

So the structure will look like...

[image]

Comment: this question might be too broad to answer. there are many ways to do this.

Comment: Pixelbits Can you please help me with any one way ?

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is a little bit outdated, I stumbled with the same issue in Angular CLI 7 and 8.

According to Angular documentation you could use '--resourceOutputPath' and '--deployUrl'. Unfortunately --resourceOutputPath only works for assets defined in stylesheet and '--deployUrl' doesn't put the assets in a folder.

My current solution is:

1. set the 'baseHref' option in the build config to '/static-files/'
2. copy the index.html file from the output folder and put it 1 folder up.

Now you end with a structure like

```
/dist
   index.html
   /static-files
      chunk1.js
      chunk2.js
      etc
```

Of course now all your assets are in a separate folder and not only your js files. But it works for me.

Note: when you also using the Angular Routing, you need to set the 'APP_BASE_HREF' manual because otherwise the router is looking for 'staric-files' in your url (https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular ClI, then create multiple NgModules, and use Lazyload in the Router. Then, when you build `ng build --prod`, each module will be in a separate file.

Below are a couple of recommended articles regarding lazyload:
http://blog.angular-university.io/angular2-ngmodule/
https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html

Comment: Thanks Tuong Le. But I have put *.chunk.js and *.map file in dist/modules folder. I hope you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a separate build package like gup or grunt, that will make the chunk files sent to a separate folder. or otherwise you can also create a Compiler option{ outDir: 'src/chunk'} in tsconfig.json. See if this solves your issue.

Comment: Please be more specific on how it should implement what you are suggesting. Just to ask the OP to try to build a whole new build pipe using Gulp or Grunt with the hope that maybe this will solve the issue is not very helpful.